# How to close gvim from command prompt

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

Usually, we open gvim from the command line like this:

```
gvim someFile.txt
```

But how are we going to close it from command line too? Instead of closing it from gvim itself?

I wanted to do some automation, hence, will need to close it from command line.

Comment: Why are you trying to open `gvim` in an automation script? I think, for automation purpose, `sed`/`awk` could be better options. Even if you want to use vim, use a VIMscript, which gets generated as part of your automation script & open VIM with `vim -S $VIMSCRIPT_PATH`. Keep `qall` as last statement in that script.

Comment: @anishsane I have had problems where I can't get to the window and still want to close it cleanly especially if the console still works! (i.e. I at times get a hard mouse lock up but the keyboard works)

Answer (score 3):

gVIM has the ability to act in client/server manner. That means you can send commands to a running vim.

Do the following

1. Start GVIM, open a document, do whatever
2. Run the following command to close GVIM

   ```
   vim --servername GVIM --remote-send '<C-\><C-N>:wq<CR>'
   ```

That will save the file in GVIM and close GVIM.

Comment: Does this close all instances of gvim?

Answer (score 1):

First, why are you automating using a gui application?

But you can close it by sending it either `<ESC>ZZ` or `:q!`

Comment: I think OP has a good reason and probably knows how to close his gvim window from within gvim. In my case, my mouse was dead and thus I could not click on that window. Although Alt-Tab usually works, it does not work across right when I open a gvim across an SSH connection. So having a way to send a message is perfect to close a window when some things are dead...